# Excel Macro read cell values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am looking to put together a program simply

It reads a line in excel A1:E1

If A1 has a value it moves to B1 if B1 has a value it moves to C1 etc.

Then it stops on the last cell with a value.

Then it saves the file based on the cell value.

I ended up with this code.

```
Sub NamePDF()
    Dim fp As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    fp = "C:\Users\mdowney\Desktop\TestFolder\" & Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fp, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Right now I know how to get a value using Lookup =LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:E1<>""),A1:E1) Now to make this a macro

Comment: Think it may use .End(xlUp).Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
activeworkbook.saveas "C:\temp\" & cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft) & ".xlsx"
```

This will not save the macros with the workbook though.

Comment: Question why wont that read dates? Example 7-Jun-12 causes error

Comment: Its that its recorded 6/7/2012 and slash marks cant go in files

Comment: in which case, you could use `format(cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft),"yyy-mm-dd")` to circumvent the `/` issue